# I'm try to count each occurence from sublists in a main list and make a graph

Tags: python, pandas, list, data-visualization

This is the list:

```
for i in programming_skills_list:
    print i
 output: ['SQL', 'C', 'Excel']
['R', 'SQL', 'C']
['SQL', 'C']
['R', 'SQL', 'C']
['SQL', 'C']
['R', 'C']
['R', 'C']
['R', 'C', 'Excel']
['R', 'SQL', 'C', 'Excel']
['R', 'Tableau', 'SQL', 'C']
['R', 'Tableau', 'SQL', 'C', 'Excel']
['R', 'C', 'Excel', 'Office']
['R', 'C', 'Excel', 'Office']
['R', 'C', 'Excel', 'Office']
['R', 'C', 'Excel', 'Office']
['SQL']
['R', 'Tableau', 'SQL', 'C']
['R', 'Tableau', 'SQL', 'C', 'Excel']
['Tableau', 'SQL', 'C', 'Excel']
['R', 'SQL', 'C']
['R', 'C', 'Excel', 'Office']
['R', 'C', 'Excel', 'Office']
['R', 'C']
['R', 'C']
['R', 'C']
['R', 'C']
['SAS', 'R', 'C', 'Excel']
['SAS', 'R', 'Tableau', 'SQL', 'C', 'Excel', 'JMP']
['R', 'C', 'Excel']
['R', 'C', 'Excel', 'Office']
['R', 'SQL', 'C']
['R', 'SQL', 'C']
['R', 'C', 'Excel', 'Office']
['SAS', 'R', 'C']
['R', 'C', 'Excel', 'Office']
['R', 'C', 'Visual Basic', 'Excel']
['R', 'C', 'Visual Basic', 'Excel']
['SAS', 'R', 'SQL', 'C']
['SAS', 'R', 'SQL', 'C']
['SAS', 'R', 'SQL', 'C']
['R', 'C']
['R', 'SQL', 'C', 'Excel']
['SAS', 'R', 'SQL', 'C', 'Excel']
['R', 'C', 'Excel']
['R', 'C', 'Excel']
['R', 'C', 'Excel']
['R', 'C', 'Excel']
['R', 'Tableau', 'SQL', 'C', 'Excel']
['R', 'C', 'Excel', 'Office']
['R', 'C', 'Excel', 'Office']
['R', 'C', 'Excel', 'Office']
['R', 'C']
['R', 'C']
['R', 'C']
['R', 'C', 'Excel', 'Office']
['R', 'C', 'Excel', 'Office']
['R', 'C', 'Excel', 'Office']
['R', 'C', 'Excel', 'Office']
['R', 'C', 'Excel', 'Office']
['R', 'SQL', 'C']
```

Total number of sub-lists is 60. I would like to count each skill type and make a graph which shows the most required skills for a sample of 60 jobs. I tried used If statements to count but I get the error stating that list is not hashable.

Comment: Please show some code (including possibly a exemple of data structure) you've worked on so far.

Answer (score 1):

We can use pandas to get value counts and plot:

```
import pandas as pd
programming_skills_list = #however you defined that list of list above#
s = pd.Series(sum(programming_skills_list, []))
s.value_counts().plot.bar()
```

Output:

[image]